# Finding a PHP based product manager

Tags: php, product-management

I'm looking to find an user friendly PHP app to manage my client's collection of vintage tools. I can't find ANYTHING to just simply organize his collection. The closest thing I can find is a shopping cart, but that's not what he needs, as he doesn't want to sell his collection. I don't have the time to code this myself and he's getting agitated because this is taking longer than I promised.

Any suggestions? I'm sure there's SOMETHING out there.

Answer (score 2):

If it is really as simple as you make it sound, why not just write a quick and dirty script to do it yourself?

Set up 1 table in MySQL with the appropriate fields, and a couple PHP scripts to display and add/delete/update the records?

I could probably have this done in under an hour.

Answer (score 0):

there are a few options listed [here](http://www.codango.com/php/dir/webapps/ecommerc/catalogu/). I used the wordpress cart plugin once. It wasn't too hard to take out the pricing back and front end code out. I recommend the latter.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to catalog the tools I would suggest Wordpress with a Image/Photo gallery plug-in with a LightBox popup to group them together if needed. Just use the tags to add a description and well as a grouping tag if needed to group the tools together. This is probably not the solution you wanted but it might just be what would work. I was thinking showcase instead of inventory :)